# Close prevention of Internet Explorer in Windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce

I have a web application which is run on Windows CE's Internet Explorer. Is it possible to run it on full screen and disable possibility to close Internet Explorer except some special key combination? I don't have standard F11 key on my device.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out-of-the-box Internet Explorer application ships in full source form with Platform Builder as the IESAMPLE component.  Your best bet it to just clone IESAMPLE and modify the application behavior as you see fit (preventing close/removing the close button, etc).

Comment: Thank you for answer. In my MSDN subsriber's downloads I can find "Windows CE .NET 4.2 CDx", "Windows CE .NET 4.1 CDx" and "Windows Embedded CE 5.0 Disc x". Tell me please which one should I use?

Comment: If you're using CE 5.0, then the 5.0 version would make the most sense.